# Why previous file that has been replaced to new file is not in recycle bin Windows 11?

Tags: windows, data-recovery, windows-11, recycle-bin, recovery

In Windows whenever we replace some file with new file Windows deletes the old version file permanently. We don't have option to undo the changes, that file is not in recycle bin and even there are no previous version available, from prperties to previous version tab. How to make Windows to not delete them permanently. Even if we undo move/copy still we can't retrieve that previous file? Is there any solution?

Comment: that has always been windows behavior, that is why we do backups of important files.

Comment: @Moab Hi, do you know where to search #case no microsoft opened for me. – 
Thank you for contacting Microsoft Support - a support case has been opened for you.

For your reference:
Case #: 1043481038
Created on: Sunday, September 4, 2022 5:26 PM
Description: add .webp support in your Images app. 
Remember, Microsoft will never ask for your password as part of any support interaction. Also, please don´t send any financial or personal information in email.

Thanks,
Microsoft Support

Answer (score 2):

Try using Windows File Version control for this use you described.

[File Versions](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/how-to-windows-file-versioning.html)

Windows comes with many great built-in tools that, unfortunately, are hard to discover and even harder to use. One of these is its built-in file versioning tool called File History. Once set up, it can keep copies of old versions of all your files and documents. It can be incredibly useful to restore a previous version of a file or a folder after you’ve made an accidental change or deletion.

```
To get started, open File History from the Control Panel or by searching for it (press the Windows key + S).
Click Select Drive.

Once you’ve selected a disk to use with file History, find the disk or network share you chose in Windows File Explorer.
Right-click on it and select Properties.
Under Attributes click Advanced.
Enable compression and click OK on both dialogs.
When prompted, confirm that you want to apply the change to the folder and its contents.
```

This is a reasonable solution to your issue. It is not really a Recycle Bin issue. And, for sure, you need to keep current backups. I back up (sync) my documents with my other computer so one computer for sure has a good version of a document if I should screw up.

If you have a Server and are on a Domain, Windows Servers have versioning control.

Comment: Why its saying *"no usable drives were found"*.

Comment: I do backups too with this helpful software [Beyond Compare 4](https://www.scootersoftware.com/)

Comment: Are you trying to use a removable drive for file history?

Comment: I use that tool as well

Comment: Nope, I don't want any external drive to do that task.

Comment: The rules for drives you can use are well laid out in the article I posted